# Interpreting the results of p-value and Cramer's V value

Tags: chi-squared-test, p-value, data-mining, cramers-v

For my assignment I am working on a data set with the sample size **n = 4.000.000** and about **450 columns**. I have **4 rows** in my cross table that have the values winter, spring, summer and fall. So my cross table looks something like this:

```
         red   blue ... green 
winter   300   200  ...  100
spring    40   200  ...  100
summer   290   300  ...   90
fall      50   120  ...  100
```

I want to determine if the data is seasonal and for that I am using the chi-squared test combined with the Cramer's V value for the effect size. 
The results for the above values are the following:

```
                   Chi-square test     results
0  Pearson Chi-square ( 1350.0) =   91128.9836
1                       p-value =       0.0000
2                    Cramer's V =       0.0875
```

Now I see I have a small p-value because the sample size is big but is it safe to say that the data is to a small degree seasonal as the variations of appearances is relatively small because the effect size of the Cramer V tells me that. Although the data is seasonal when only observing the p-value, the Cramer V value relativizes the seasonality.

Also can you recommend me a good statistiical book or article that explains the relation between those two values? 
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your conclusions are correct.

Cramer's $\Psi$ is simply the chi square statistic divided by its maximum possible value, while Cramer's V is its sqare root.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @carlo. Would you also say that the statistical tests are legit as my sample size is very large.

Comment: yes, why shouldn't they be?

Comment: Because in https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/262b/854628d8e2b073816935d82b5095e1703977.pdf/ the problem of the usage of p-value is discussed. And obviously I do have a large sample size so I was not sure about it. But on the other hand the result I have is not surprising at all if my conclusions are right. So I was not sure about it.

Comment: if you simulate a dataset of 4000000 random and independent values for your problem, chi square test will give you a non significant p-value 19 times out of 20 (for alpha = 0.05), there is nothing like a sample too large. problem is if you mistake statistical significance for practical significance.

Comment: Ok, so it would be unnecessary to even calculate the p-value in my case as it is almost always non significant? Or would it make sense to calculate the p-value test in combination with the Cramers V so I can truly say if the p-value is < 0.05? That was my idea to really know if the p-value really tells me that the data is highly seasonal as the value of 0.0000 suggests

Comment: quite the contrary. the p-value tells you if it's safe to say that the effect size (Cramer's V) you observed was not created by sample fluctuations. this is a problem mainly in little datasets, in large ones any effect big enough will be extremely significant, only most tiny effects can come out to be non significant. that's why p-values are little use in large datasets.

Comment: of course computing a predictably low p-value is no harm at all

Comment: So to make things clear: The magnitude of the phenomenon "seasonal", calculated with Cramer's V, is relatively small, but the phenomenon "seasonal" that is observed, is that the data is truly seasonal as the p-value is 0.000. Is that correct? Thank you for your support!

Comment: yes, pretty much so.